Physical interpretation of work done for $\int_{C}^{} Pdx$
The physical interpretation of $\int_{C}^{} \overrightarrow{F} \cdot d\overrightarrow{r} =\int_{C}^{} Pdx + Qdy$ is that it is work done by the vector (force) field along the path of the curve $C$.
Does this mean that $\int_{C}^{} Pdx$ is the work done by the vector field along the path of the curve $C$ in just the $x$ direction, and $\int_{C}^{} Qdy$ is the work done in the $y$ direction? I know that these are the areas under the projections of the functions $P$ and $Q$ along $C$ onto the $xz$ and $yz$ planes, respectively, but is that area the work done in those directions? Thank you.

You have the right idea: each summand expresses the work done by the component of the force in the given direction. Have a look at this answer about interpreting the meaning of a line integral from first principles. It's stated in pure mathematical terms, but of course you can interpret the vector field to be force field, in which case it's calculating work along a path.

@SammyBlack Thank you! I'll take a look at that post
